# Splitting covariance into variance and partial regression coefficient

Tags: regression, variance, covariance

I've been reading this [paper](http://www.ceacb.ucl.ac.uk/cultureclub/files/2004-2005/CC2005-06-23-Henrich2004.pdf).

The paper starts with the [Price equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_equation) and does some transformations on it. When proceeding from equation (7) to equation (8) it replaces covariances with variances multiplied by a partial regression coefficient, like this:

[image]

becomes

[image]

Are these two really equivalent? My feeling is that the distribution of wj has an effect in the first case, but in the second case it's reduced to a single number.

If they are not equivalent, what's the assumption that has to be made to make them equivalent?